# List of Figures: How do I get a vertical space between figures from my final chapter and my first appendix?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm using `tocloft` with the `report` document class.  I have four chapters and some appendices.  My List of Figures produces vertical spacing between figures from different chapters, but it does *not* add a vertical space between the last figure from my last chapter and the first figure from my first appendix:

```
3.7
3.8
     <-- appropriate spacing
4.1
4.2
A1   <-- no preceding v-space
A2
```

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong (and/or how to fix this)?

Comment: With `\appendix 
\chapter{Appendix}` you'll get the wanted space also before the appendix part. If not, then you did something different!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default behaviour in `report` with or without [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) is to add a vertical space of `10pt` in the ToC, LoF and LoT whenever you use `\chapter`. If you use `\chapter*` for a similar chapter look-and-feel but no numbering, no entry is written to the ToC and this space is dropped.

There are many ways to insert this "missing" gap, the easiest of which would just be to add

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
```

at the start of your appendix. This adds the traditional `10pt` space, but won't add more than that (due to `\addvspace`; rather than `\vspace` alone). For example, if the previous chapter didn't include any figures, you don't want double the gap between the LoF entries. This solution is independent of the use of `tocloft`.

Here is a minimal example:

[image: Add vertical space between figures in LoF after appendix]

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\chapter{A chapter}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\appendix
\chapter*{A chapter}
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption{A figure}\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was my problem: I was using \chapter*{}.  Thanks very much for  setting me straight!